# Are there any summoning spells on the warlock spell list that don't require high Charisma to be effective?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, warlock, ability-scores, summoning

Me and my friends are running a campaign in D&D 5e. I am playing a Genie-patron (Marid) Pact of the Blade warlock (with a 1-level fighter dip at the start) currently.

My Str and Con scores are 16 (and I have proficiency bonus to these saving throws because I started with 1 level in fighter). My Cha score is 14, and I don't plan to increase it; I want to increase my Str for melee combat instead.

I've looked at the Warlock spell list, and there are ok options for Warlocks who don't have high Charisma. I'm looking at the summoning spells (because I like summoning spells), but a lot of them generally need Charisma one way or another; either the creature that I summoned uses my spellcasting ability for its attack rolls, or I need to convince it to be on my side (for the fiend-summoning spells).

Are there any summoning spells in the warlock spell list that don't require high Charisma to be effective?

Comment: Hey mate, just added a dnd-5e tag to the question so that 5e experts can find this question easier!

Comment: "My Str and Con scores are 16, and I have proficiency bonus to these skills because I started with 1 level in fighter" - Fighters start with proficiency in Str and Con *saving throws*; note that these aren't skills, and this proficiency doesn't apply to ability checks made using those abilities either.

Answer (score 4):

### Unfortunately no, not in the usual sense

Warlocks just lack good summoning options in general. *Tasha's Cauldron of Everything* tried to address this problem with some spells, that are really good with the condition that you actually increase  your Charisma. This, however, does not mean you cannot use them effectively.

I'll say that there are some options, depending on your needs:

#### Tanking

[*Summon Aberration*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/summon-aberration) with Slaad chosen can be of great help, not for his consistent damage, but for regeneration. That means you can use this slaadi as a damage sponge, and as long as you do not let him die, he can be used through multiple encounters, reducing damage your team would take. Bonus points for a following fact: if a trap will not kill it in one go, it can be used for trap triggering, serving as a fairly long 15-foot stick.

And that's all - unless we include [Eldritch Invocations](https://www.dndbeyond.com/classes/warlock#EldritchInvocations-388). Then, at 9th-level warlock, you can take the Minions of Chaos invocation, allowing you to summon elementals, which are completely independent from your spellcasting ability, and are almost always a decent choice.

#### Control

[*Summon Shadowspawn*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/summon-shadowspawn) with Despair chosen is good for battlefield control. It has an aura that decreases movement speed by 20 feet for anything other than you in a 5-foot radius at the start of the creature's turn. It's not dependent on a roll; it just happens. If you want to go for kiting with a ranged or reach weapon, this is an excellent choice. An ability to give out fear in AoE is less effective, but movement speed reduction is still great, giving you ability to outmaneuver any creature with less than 40 feet of movement.

#### Damage

Well, damage output strongly depends on your to-hit bonus, so there really aren't any "good" options in your case.

If we include Eldritch Invocations, then at 9th-level warlock, you can take the Minions of Chaos invocation, allowing you to summon elementals, which are completely independent from your spellcasting ability, and are almost always a decent choice.

#### Bonus utility

If you would consider this is worth investing a feat, you could take the Magic Initiate feat (or, if you have an Int or Wis score of 13, the Ritual Caster feat is an option), and pick *find familiar* as your chosen spell. A familiar is very versatile, costs next to nothing, and can even help with combat by taking the Help action, increasing your chance to hit or crit.

Beside those, I am not aware of any decent options that would suit your needs. You already picked Pact of the Blade, so Pact of the Chain isn't really an option.

Comment: Wow. Really good list. Thank you.